# SQL Server 2014 In-Memory tables

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database, sql-server-2014

For the past couple of weeks I sort of tested the new In-Memory thing in SQL Server 2014 (never worked with SQL Server 2012, jumped from 2008R2 straight to 2014, so if this new feature is present in SQL Server 2012 as well, my bad).

One of the things I was curious about is to see the "physical" space allocated to a particular memory optimized table.

The `sys.allocation_units` seems to no longer hold information about the pages used by this new type of table, which makes sense considering that the table is no longer stored in pages. So I found out that for this you need to use the `sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats` VIEW (which is again new to me, perhaps this was present in the 2012 edition).

As I mentioned above, this was a view so I wanted to see what is the underlying table that holds this information but when I "unwrapped" the code behind the view `sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats`, this is what I got:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats
AS
SELECT
    object_id,
    memory_allocated_for_table_kb,
    memory_used_by_table_kb,
    memory_allocated_for_indexes_kb,
    memory_used_by_indexes_kb
FROM
    sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats$
WHERE database_id = db_id()
```

Now what the heck is with that dollar sign next to that table (which is not a table btw!). I googled a bit about it and didn't come up with any hits for this. Is that something as an engine table pointer?
Any clues?

Comment: My guess, and it's nothing more, is that it indicates some kind of hidden system table, akin to the $ shared folders on a windows server

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Dont remember exactly where but I have read something about these Object names with Dollar signs. These are the System Tables that are not available to public. And requires some sort of Super Permissions (Higher than SA-- Only Microsoft Development Team) to query them. Therefore an average user even an SA gets an error as it is not available for us.